# df.loc and value count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to get the first letter of a column and then get the value counts for that letter

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df['EmployeeLastName'].astype(str).str[0].value_counts())
```

and then select only the values that are more than 50

```
df5.loc[df5['EmployeeLastName'] > 50]
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this without creating a new data frame?

I tried this put it is resulting in an error.

```
df.loc[ df['EmployeeLastName'].astype(str).str[0].value_counts() > 50 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: or other way is `df['EmployeeLastName'].astype(str).str[0].value_counts().pipe(lambda x:x[x.gt(50)])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `transform`

```
df.loc[(df.groupby(df['EmployeeLastName'].str[0])
          .transform('count') > 50).squeeze()]
```